# Multiplying shown NaN in angular

Tags: angular

I hope you're all doing well. Angular beginner here. I am trying to multiply two value but the result showing NaN, separate they are showing their correct values like in below code `{{product_content.product_price}} = 400` AND   `{{product_content.product_quantity}} = 1`
but when I multiply they show NaN.

```
<tr ng-repeat="product_content in product_content">
    <th>{{$index++1}}</th>
    <td>
        {{product_content.product_name}}
    </td>
    <td>
        {{product_content.product_size}}
    </td>
    <td>
        {{product_content.product_price}}
    </td>
    <td>
        {{product_content.product_quantity}}
    </td>
    <td>
        {{product_content.product_quantity * products.product_price}}
    <td>
    {{product_content.product_details}}
</tr>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a typo. Change this line

```
{{product_content.product_quantity  * products.product_price}}
```

to this

```
{{product_content.product_quantity  * product_content.product_price}}
```

Answer (score -1):

I think the data is coming string. So try putting 
{{(+product_content.product_quantity)  * (+products.product_price)}}

It'll convert string to number before multiplication.